# Rails6 save multiple records with single form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm creating an app which part of registration is a legal test. I've got a model `TestResult` which has only one field `answer:string` and it `belongs_to :test_question`. I want to enable the user to answer multiple questions in a single form in `views/test_results/new.html.erb`

- user must answer to 5 random Legal Questions from each predefined category (method `fetch_random_questions` from `TestResultsController`)
- checks radio button below each question and hits submit
- the data from **5 individual forms should get saved as 5 different records in the db on submitting just once**
- in current implementation I'm rendering submit button after each answer

Detailed code below:

models:

```
class TestResult < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :test_question

  validates :answer, presence: true
end


class TestQuestion < ApplicationRecord
  CATEGORIES = %w[Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 Q5].freeze

  has_many :test_results, dependent: :destroy
end
```

`app/controllers/TestResultsController`

```
class TestResultsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :fetch_random_questions, only: [:new, :create]

  def new
    @test_result = TestResult.new
  end

  def create
    @test_result = TestResult.new(test_result_params)

    if @test_result.save
      render :show, status: :created, location: @test_result

      redirect_to dummy_path
    else
      render json: @test_result.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  private

  def test_result_params
    params.require(:test_result).permit(:answer)
  end

  def fetch_random_questions
    test_questions = TestQuestion::CATEGORIES.map do |category|
      TestQuestion.where(question_category: category, published: true).order('RANDOM()').first
    end

    @randomize_questions = test_questions.map do |obj|
      {
        question: obj.question,
        answers: [obj.correct_answer, obj.other_answer1, obj.other_answer2, obj.other_answer3].shuffle,
      }
    end
  end
end
```

`views/test_results/new.html.erb`

```
<% @randomize_questions.each do |q| %>
  <%= simple_form_for(@test_result) do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>
    <%= f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present? %>

    <%= q[:question] %>
    <%= f.input :answer, collection: q[:answers], as: :radio_buttons %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

At the end `views/test_results/new.html.erb` should displayed data like below:

```
Q1 - first question
-answer1
-correct_answer
-answer2

Q2 - second question
-answer1
-answer2

Q3 - third question
-answer1
-answer2
-answer3
-correct_answer

(...)

Submit
```

Comment: take a look at Nested Attributes, and accepts_nested_attributes_for. it should do what you want.

Comment: @Doon thanks for that, it's really handy! But I don't understand how it should be implemented in case when I'm trying to create a new `TestResult` which belongs_to `TestQuestion`. I think Nasted Attributes would work in reverse case.

Comment: Or maybe my association is wrong?

Comment: I don't think this is a nested attributes case.

Comment: gotcha. I misunderstood.  So you want a single form that has 5 random questions. that when you submit will create 5 test results in the database? You will probably need to do it in 1 form (as opposed to multiples), and could try using a table less model to represent the questions set, and then the question set controller could persist to the correct tables. (this is just me thinking out loud). but with teh current data model is seems like it could be a bit hard (for example will you know the correct answer if you randomize them, etc..)

Comment: Yes, you are right! Well... it's really complicated, now I think it would be better to change the db model to accept a hash with all answers. No worries I would somehow manipulate the data to mark the correct answer (let's skip this part for now) but omg... how to to display these questions as a 1 form and give the user ability can select only one answer for each question? Maybe I should add some additional model? I'm really flexible, this is day 3 of my struggle...